# Procedure or Function has Too many arguments specified

Tags: vb.net

Its our old friend again.....
I am recieving this error and i cant think why. I have checked the number of parameters being passed as well as the number of required paramaters from the sp ,regenerating the data set has given me no look. I must have missed something basic. Another pair of eyes would be helpfull.

Thank you in advance

```
    Public Sub GetRows(ByVal [Option] As String, ByVal searchString As String)

    Me.DataSet11.Clear()

    SqlSelectCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    SqlSelectCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Option", [Option])
    SqlSelectCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchString", searchString.ToUpper)

    Try
        SqlConnection1.Open()
        'execute reader
        'rdr = SqlSelectCommand1.ExecuteReader
        Me.DataGridViewAvItems.DataSource = DataSet11.design_sp_search_drawings
        Me.SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11, "design_sp_search_drawing")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        'close the conenction
        SqlConnection1.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

///DESIGNER CODE

```
Me.SqlSelectCommand1.CommandText = "dbo.design_sp_search_drawings"
    Me.SqlSelectCommand1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Me.SqlSelectCommand1.Connection = Me.SqlConnection1
    Me.SqlSelectCommand1.Parameters.AddRange(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() {New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@searchString", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, "TES0201"), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Option", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, "site_code")})
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur in? Also, remove all unnecessary code, post just the relevant code (but if possible make it complete).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Me.SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11, "design_sp_search_drawing")

Comment: Its interesting, when i right click the data adapter and preview data the results are being returned.

Comment: Add the return parameter: `Dim param = New SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
SqlSelectCommand1.Parameters.Add(param)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter hi Tim - thanks for the input, I have updated the post now. Still receiving the error unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you adding the Option and SearchString parameters more than once?  In the designer code you showed at the bottom, you add the parameters @RETURN_VALUE, @searchString, and @Option with the call to AddRange and you are adding them again at the top of the code when you call AddWithValue for each one of them.  So to me it looks as if you have added 5 parameters.  Am I missing something?  What does the sproc require?

Comment: The below worked, thankyou Chris. Now i need to work out why the grid wont populate. Thanks alot dude!!

       SqlSelectCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        SqlSelectCommand1.Parameters("@Option").Value = [Option]
        SqlSelectCommand1.Parameters("@searchString").Value = searchString.ToUpper